# Textures go black when changing Quality Settings at runtime

Tags: unity, materials

Whenever I change my Quality Settings at runtime in editor mode or in build, all of my textures turn black. I use the following line to change the quality settings :

```
QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(value, true);
```

I have tried to set the boolean at false and it does the same result. I am using HDRP and the shader "HDRenderPipeline/Lit" on pretty much all of my materials. There is an interesting fact, in editor mode, I just hover my mouse on any material inspector window, it updates all of my textures back to normal and solves the problem.
Here is a screen showing the textures (left is normal, and right is bugged):
[image]
Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to change quality levels at runtime?

Comment: To enable players to chose graphic settings in game.